# HtmlAgilityPack how to extract html between some tag

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I need to extract all the paragraph from one html and also all text between that tags.

this code is not working when the text parsed into HtmlDocument get changed from the original one. In the sample

```
some <br />text
```

is changed in

```
some <br>text
```

es:

```
string s = "<p>firt paragraph</p>some <br />text<p>another paragraph</p><span>some text between span</span><p>hellow word</p>";
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(s);
var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p");
int lastPos = -1;
foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode n in nodes)
{
  if (lastPos > -1)
  {
      string textNotInP = Doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml.Substring(lastPos, n.StreamPosition - lastPos);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(textNotInP);
 }
 System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(n.OuterHtml);
 lastPos = n.StreamPosition + n.OuterHtml.Length;
}
```

the correct result would be:

```
<p>firt paragraph</p>
some <br>text
<p>second paragraph</p>
<span>some text between span</span>
<p>third paragraph</p>
```

but the code above return this:

```
<p>firt paragraph</p>
some <br>text<p
<p>second paragraph</p>
pan>some text between span</span><p
<p>third paragraph</p>
```

the reason is steamPosition return the node position related to the original text, not that one parserd in htmlDocument.

Is There a way to return the position of one node related to the parsed html?

Comment: What do you want to achieve actually? I mean, string manipulation should be last option when you already using a proper HTML parser.. why do you need to manually manipulate `OuterHtml` in the first place?

Comment: It is also confusing that sample HTML in code snippet doesn't correspond to the one shown in the 'correct result' and current result..

Comment: i just need the html between the p tags, any way is good

Comment: What is the text exactly? for example, '`firt paragraph`' (this is between opening tag and closing tag p) or '`some <br>text`' (this one is between two p elements)? which one do you mean by *'between the p tags'*?

Comment: i need the extrace all html is containing beetweb two paragrhaps. <p>some html</p>this html need to extract<p>some html</p>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `OuterHtml` property of each `<p>` element to get the desired HTML :

```
string s = "<p>firt paragraph</p>some <br />text<p>another paragraph</p><span>some text between span</span><p>hellow word</p>";
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(s);
var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p");
foreach (var item in nodes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.OuterHtml);
}
```

**output :**

```
<p>firt paragraph</p>
<p>another paragraph</p>
<p>hellow word</p>
```

Or if you mean to get everything between the first `<p>` and the last `<p>` elements, inclusive, you can use the following XPath :

```
var query = "//node()[preceding-sibling::p or self::p][following-sibling::p or self::p]";
```

The XPath grab all nodes (either element or text node) that: has preceding sibling `p` and following sibling `p`, or the node itself is a `p` element.

```
var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(query);
foreach (var item in nodes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.OuterHtml);
}
```

**output :**

```
<p>firt paragraph</p>
some
<br />
text
<p>another paragraph</p>
<span>some text between span</span>
<p>hellow word</p>
```

Comment: ok but also i need to extract the html is not contained into <p></p>

Comment: Does `<p>` has parent element in your actual HTML? What if you select the parent and output its `InnerHtml`?

Comment: I guess you want to get everything between the first `<p>` and the last `<p>` elements. Check my updated answer.